# Simple division function in IA32 assembly

Tags: assembly, intel, x86

I am working on an assignment for my class. My C++ code calls the `_Divide` function to take in 2 values to divide and return into 'Result'. To start I move -1 into eax. Once I'm done with the process, my eax keeps returning '-1' as the value. What could I be doing wrong? Here's my assem code:

```
public _Divide
.386
.model flat
.code
_Divide   proc
      mov eax, -1
      mov ebx, 1

      cdq
      idiv ebx
      ret
_Divide   endp
   end
```

Here's my C++ code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" long Divide (long, long, long *);
void main ()
{
long    Result;
long    Remainder;
long    Dividend;
long    Divisor;
 do {
  cout << "Enter Dividend" << endl; 
  cin >> Dividend;
  cout << "Enter Divisor" << endl;
  cin >> Divisor;
  Result = Divide (Dividend, Divisor, &Remainder);
  cout << "Result is " << Result << " and Remainder is " << Remainder << endl;
 } while ((Result >= 0) || (Remainder != 0));
 Result = Divide (Dividend, Divisor, 0);
 cout << "Result is " << Result << " and Remainder is not used" << endl;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Format your code next time - instructions are on the edit page.

Answer (score 4):

Your code divides `-1` by `1`.  The answer is `-1`, so that's what you return.  Let's break down the code (I'll just put inline comments):

```
mov eax, -1      ; Put -1 in eax
mov ebx, 1       ; put  1 in ebx

cdq              ; sign extend eax -> edx:eax = -1
idiv ebx         ; divide edx:eax (-1) by ebx (1)
                 ;   result goes in eax, so now eax = -1
ret              ; return eax (-1) to caller
```

If you want to divide arguments passed to this function, you need to access them somehow.  You didn't show us the C++ function signature, so I can't help you with any more details than that.

Hint:  If you're writing IA32 code, which it looks like you're doing, the arguments will be on the stack.

Comment: Thanks Carl, I see what you are saying. We've been programming in the _asm{} block and we've always had specific values to give to our registers. Since the values need to be taken in from stack, I'm guessing, I'm not sure how that would work

Comment: @justbrianr, you can check out the link in @Andrey's answer for information on calling conventions.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write function in assembly you should learn about calling conventions first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions . Basically calling convention is the set of agreement between caller and function on how they will pass and return values.

Usual convention for C++ is usually `__cdecl` or `__stdcall`. Both require return value to be passed via `EAX`. Since `EAX` always have -1 this is what you get.